# Problemas al convertir consulta SQL a JSON

Tags: sql-server

Tengo el siguiente Procedimiento:

```
CREATE PROC GET_PAGINAS
AS
SELECT PAGINAS.ID_PAGINA, PAGINAS.ID_SECCION, PAGINAS.DESCRIPCION,
PERMISOS.ID_PERMISO, PERMISOS.APLICA
FROM IH_PAGINAS PAGINAS
JOIN IH_PAGINAS_PERMISOS PERMISOS ON PERMISOS.ID_PAGINA=PAGINAS.ID_PAGINA
FOR JSON AUTO
GO
```

Esto me genera un json incompleto:

```
[{"ID_PAGINA":1,"ID_SECCION":1,"DESCRIPCION":"Nueva Habitación","PERMISOS":[{"ID_PERMISO":1,"APLICA":1},{"ID_PERMISO":2,"APLICA":0},{"ID_PERMISO":3,"APLICA":0},{"ID_PERMISO":4,"APLICA":0}]},{"ID_PAGINA":2,"ID_SECCION":1,"DESCRIPCION":"Habitaciones","PERMISOS":[{"ID_PERMISO":1,"APLICA":0},{"ID_PERMISO":2,"APLICA":1},{"ID_PERMISO":3,"APLICA":1},{"ID_PERMISO":4,"APLICA":1}]},{"ID_PAGINA":3,"ID_SECCION":2,"DESCRIPCION":"Nueva Reservacion","PERMISOS":[{"ID_PERMISO":1,"APLICA":1},{"ID_PERMISO":2,"APLICA":0},{"ID_PERMISO":3,"APLICA":0},{"ID_PERMISO":4,"APLICA":0}]},{"ID_PAGINA":4,"ID_SECCION":2,"DESCRIPCION":"Reservaciones","PERMISOS":[{"ID_PERMISO":1,"APLICA":0},{"ID_PERMISO":2,"APLICA":1},{"ID_PERMISO":3,"APLICA":1},{"ID_PERMISO":4,"APLICA":1}]},{"ID_PAGINA":5,"ID_SECCION":3,"DESCRIPCION":"Nuevo Activo","PERMISOS":[{"ID_PERMISO":1,"APLICA":1},{"ID_PERMISO":2,"APLICA":0},{"ID_PERMISO":3,"APLICA":0},{"ID_PERMISO":4,"APLICA":0}]},{"ID_PAGINA":6,"ID_SECCION":3,"DESCRIPCION":"Activos","PERMISOS":[{"ID_PERMISO":1,"APLICA":0},{"ID_PERMISO":2,"APLICA":1},{"ID_PERMISO":3,"APLICA":1},{"ID_PERMISO":4,"APLICA":1}]},{"ID_PAGINA":7,"ID_SECCION":4,"DESCRIPCION":"Nuevo Beneficio","PERMISOS":[{"ID_PERMISO":1,"APLICA":1},{"ID_PERMISO":2,"APLICA":0},{"ID_PERMISO":3,"APLICA":0},{"ID_PERMISO":4,"APLICA":0}]},{"ID_PAGINA":8,"ID_SECCION":4,"DESCRIPCION":"Beneficios","PERMISOS":[{"ID_PERMISO":1,"APLICA":0},{"ID_PERMISO":2,"APLICA":1},{"ID_PERMISO":3,"APLICA":1},{"ID_PERMISO":4,"APLICA":1}]},{"ID_PAGINA":9,"ID_SECCION":5,"DESCRIPCION":"Nuevo Descuento","PERMISOS":[{"ID_PERMISO":1,"APLICA":1},{"ID_PERMISO":2,"APLICA":0},{"ID_PERMISO":3,"APLICA":0},{"ID_PERMISO":4,"APLICA":0}]},{"ID_PAGINA":10,"ID_SECCION":5,"DESCRIPCION":"Descuentos","PERMISOS":[{"ID_PERMISO":1,"APLICA":0},{"ID_PERMISO":2,"APLICA":1},{"ID_PERMISO":3,"APLICA":1},{"ID_PERMISO":4,"APLICA":1}]},{"ID_PAGINA":11,"ID_SECCION":6,"DESCRIPCION":"Nuevo Impuesto","PERMISOS":[{"ID_PERMISO":1,"APLICA":1},{"ID_PERMISO":2,"APLICA":0},{"ID_PERMISO":3,"APLICA":0},{"ID_PERMISO":4,
```

Es como si no alcanzara a convertir toda la consulta a JSON.

La tabla sin la conversión a JSON es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven, tiene bastantes campos, la consulta es porque se corta el JSON ?

Esta es la consulta que hago al back-end.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si lo ejecutas directamente en el Management Studio te muestra el json completo?

Answer (score 0):

Ya logré solucionarlo, al parecer, se corta porque JSON en SQL Server está diseñado para consultas cortas, así que para que salga completo, la consulta debe guardarse en una variable con nvarchar(max):

```
declare @prueba nvarchar(max)

set @prueba= (
 SELECT PAGINAS.ID_PAGINA, SECCIONES.NOM_SECCION, PAGINAS.ID_SECCION, PAGINAS.DESCRIPCION,PERMISOS.ID_PERMISO,
 LECTURA.ID_PERMISO, LECTURA.APLICA
    FROM IH_PAGINAS PAGINAS 
    JOIN IH_PAGINAS_PERMISOS LECTURA ON LECTURA.ID_PAGINA=PAGINAS.ID_PAGINA
    JOIN IH_PERMISOS PERMISOS ON PERMISOS.ID_PERMISO = LECTURA.ID_PERMISO
    JOIN IH_SECCIONES SECCIONES ON SECCIONES.ID_SECCION=PAGINAS.ID_SECCION
    ORDER BY (SECCIONES.NOM_SECCION)
    FOR JSON AUTO 
    )
    select  @prueba as PRUEBA 
    return
```